# Custom BST (based on apalike) with following sorting mechanism: (1) First author only, (2) Year, (3) All (other) authors, (4) Title

Tags: bibtex, natbib, apa-style, sorting, custom-bib

Following https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/484079/ I have created a custom BST, based on the `apalike` bibliographystyle of the `natbib` package in bibtex.

This custom BST orders references in the bibliography according to this pattern:

(1) Name of first author only

(2) Year of publication

(3) Title of publication

It also sorts all one-author items first, then all two-author items and finally all three-or-more-author items.

The only functional change made to the `apalike` style applies to `FUNCTION {sort.format.names}` (ll. 914-934) which gives the above-mentioned pattern and was replaced by:

```
FUNCTION {sort.format.names}
{ 's :=
  s num.names$ #0 >
    {
       s #1 "{vv{ } }{ll{ }}{  f{ }}{  jj{ }}" format.name$
       s num.names$
       duplicate$ #3 <
         { int.to.str$ * }
         {
           pop$
           "3" *
         }
       if$
    }
    { "" }
  if$
}
```

(all credit for this function goes to user https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/35864/moewe)

How can I modify this code to get the following sorting pattern:

(1) Name of first author only

(2) Year of publication

(3) Name of all (other) authors

(4) Title of publication

?

This change will obviously only affect publications with more than one author.

If possible I would prefer to use this custom BST, i. e. a bibtex solution, not a biblatex solution.